# JAXB java.util.Date deserialization issue( RESTeasy )

Tags: javascript, java, jaxb, jackson, resteasy

I have java.util.Date field in my server side, like this

```
 @XmlElement(name = "start-before", required = true)
 private java.util.Date startBefore;
```

I sent data from my client as long value like : **1440652359927**. 
In client side I convert this from user input, like below

```
 new Date("Thu Aug 27 2015 10:42:34 AM");
```

and send it to server side.

In server side I use : jboss, RESTeasy.

When I try it manually in Java side as **new Date(1440652359927)** it works fine but by RESTeasy the year field gets some error like **Thu Mar 27 04:42:25 IST 84921692**

Anyone please help me on this.

EDIT: issue is not in REST it is in JAXB unmarsheller

when I give input as long value that will convert like that.I have test this in local JAXB test environment( Not in REST ), also my REST api not allow java.util.Date as String.